# Step in proof: given an operator $S$, mapping a polynomial $p$ defined on the spectrum to $p(S)$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm reading in Rynne and Youngson's Linear Functional Analysis book, and I have a question about Lemma 6.57. It says:

> Let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbert space, and let $\mathcal S$ be the real Banach space of all self-adjoint operators in $B(\mathcal H$) (the space of bounded linear operators). If $S\in\mathcal S$ then there exists $\Phi\in B(C_{\mathbb R}(\sigma(S)),\mathcal S)$ such that $\Phi(p)=p(S)$ whenever $p$ is a polynomial in $C_{\mathbb R(\sigma(S))}$.

Notation: $\sigma(S)$ denotes the spectrum of $S$, $C_{\mathbb R}(\sigma(S),\mathcal S)$ denotes the space of continuous functions from $\sigma(S)$ to $\mathcal S$ (endowed with the uniform metric), $B(X,Y)$ is the space of bounded linears operators for a normed space, and $B(X)=B(X,X)$.

The proof proof starts by considering the linear subspace $\mathcal P\subset C_{\mathbb R}(\sigma(S))$ of polynomials, and defining $\phi(p)=p(S)$ (which will later be extended to $\Phi$).

My problem is that I don't see why this is well-defined. What I basically want to show is that if we have a polynomial $p$ that vanishes on $\sigma(S)$, then $p(S)$ must also vanish.

The claim is easily verified if we have a basis of eigenvectors for $S$. Also it's clear that as soon as $\sigma(S)$ has infinitely many values, there cannot be two polynomials that restrict to the same function on $\sigma(S)$. However I don't see why it's true when $\sigma(S)$ is finite.

Comment: @geetha290krm That's not correct. The assumption is that $S$ is self-adjoint, and therefore $\sigma(S)=\{0\}$ implies that $S=0$.

Comment: We have the equality $\sigma(p(S))=p(\sigma(S)).$ This is true for any operator. Hence $\|p(S)\|=\sup_{t\in\sigma(S)}|p(t)|$ as $p(S)$ is normal. For normal operators the operator norm and the spectral radius coincide.

Comment: Ah, nice, that's it. So it works well because the spectrum behaves well with polynomial operations. If you want to copy your comment and post as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the equality $\sigma(p(S))=p(\sigma(S)).$ This is true for any bounded operator in a Hilbert space. Hence $\|p(S)\|=\displaystyle\sup_{t\in\sigma(S)}|p(t)|$ as $p(S)$ is normal. For normal operators the operator norm and the spectral radius coincide.

Comment: Could I ask you a question? I understand that $p(S)$ is normal because $S$ is normal. But what if $p$ is not a polynomial, but a function from the disk algebra? Because my Prof told me, that in this case, it's not so trivial that $p(S)$ would be normal. Instead, we should use a "construction from the functional calculus" (I don't know if it's the proper translation, in Polish it's "użyć konstrukcję ciągłego rachunku funkcyjnego") or to use the spectral theorem (to try to represent $p(S)$ as a spectral integral/"całka spektralna").